# Array_filter to unset value from array

Tags: php, arrays

I don't want to use foreach loop in my code and to unset array element from the array so I tried below code but it is not working as expected.

```
<?php 
$arr = array(array('0'=>'test','1'=>'test1','images'=>'data'),array('0'=>'test','1'=>'test1','images'=>'data'),array('0'=>'test','1'=>'test1','images'=>'data'),array('0'=>'test','1'=>'test1','images'=>'data'));
$arr1 = array_filter($arr,function ($item) use ($my_value) {    
    if(array_key_exists('images',$item)) {unset($item['images']);}
    return $item;});
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($arr1);
    echo "</pre>";
    die;
```

I want to remove key 'images' from the array but this code returns actual array.

What is the error in this code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use **array_map()** instead of using `array_filter`,

The `array_map()` will map each value of your array and create a new array with new values with new operations performed.

```
 $arr1 = array_map(function($tmp) { unset($tmp['images']); return $tmp; }, $arr);
```

Here is a **[Reference Link](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_map.asp)** for **array_map()**.

Answer (score 1):

You can use array_map() instead of array_filter()

```
$arr1 = array_map(function($tmp) { unset($tmp['images']); return $tmp; }, $arr); 

print_r($arr1);
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can do this by updating existing array without assigning new array**

You can use this:

```
array_walk($ararray_walk($arr, function(&$v, $k) { // Pass the values by reference
    if(array_key_exists('images', $v)){
        unset($v['images']);
    }
});
print_r($arr);
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/UK0ne)